# Using setState of functional component inside a new Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I know that setting state is async, but is there a use case for setting a state inside a new promise? I do not understand promises to be honest, they are difficult to understand and their use cases baffle me. But I know that sometimes I setState and I console.log it and it's undefined. I wanna go around that by putting it into a new Promise. Is this a correct approach? In terms of my code snippet, how would I even structure that logic? I don't know what the if would be checking for.

```js
      onRowClicked={row=>{
      const trial = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
       let setter = setRowIndex(row.index)
        if(setter) {
          resolve()
       } else {
          reject();
       }
       })
```

Comment: setState and promises are unrelated - your issue *I setState and I console.log it and it's undefined* is something else - but without actual code, it's an unknown something else

Comment: I am just setting the state to true and then console logging it and it is showing the previous state. It's just setState followed by console.log.

Answer (score 0):

you want to print updated state, to accomplish that it depends how you are using react.

- class component: you can print `this.state` at `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method. Alternatively, at `this.setState` function you can pass a second argument, a function that runs after `this.state` is updated;
- hooks: use `useEffect` to run on state updates like: `useEffect(() => console.log(myState) ,[myState])`

Comment: This is awesome thank you! So what would I use a new Promise then? any example?

Comment: well async calls, like when you make a request to an API to get data with `fetch` or `axios`, they are promise based. you can chain them with `then` method. this method is called when the promise is successfull. you can for example do `axios.get(url).then((response) => this.setState({ data: response}))`. but  you don't create a promise to print current state.

Comment: right I understand that any fetch call is Async. However, when you create a new Promise it's different than fetch. What is the usecase of new Promise?